# How to set current user to user field in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following code working perfectly. I can create a `Post` object from DRF panel by selecting an image and a user. However I want DRF to populate the user field by the currently logged in user.

**models.py**

```
class Post(TimeStamped):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload/')
    hidden = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    upvotes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    downvotes = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    comments = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'photo']
```

**views.py**

```
class PhotoListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(hidden=False)
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you can just override the `perform_create()` method:

```
class PhotoListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ...
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Give that a shot and let me know if it works

Comment: Hi. What if I use `def validate_user(self, value):
        return self.context['request'].user` on `serializers.py` file. That works too. Is there any internal difference between these two?

Comment: @MiniGunnR That's fine too, assuming you want the user to be part of the serialization. My method will work regardless.

Comment: If the field 'user' is required, you will never reach that method - perform_create yet because the raise exception in create method. That is my case.

Comment: When you want to disable the field in the browsable api set it as read_only https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-read-only-fields

Comment: To anyone reading this answer in 2019: you should also pass kwargs, so you can do it like this:

```
    def perform_create(self, serializer, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user'] = self.request.user
        serializer.save(**kwargs)
```

Comment: @DataGreed Is there a reason to pass `kwargs` in 2019? I fail to see how this is necessary when the `create` method doesn't provide `kwargs` by default.(source: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/mixins.py)

Comment: @DaveBensonPhillips how do I fetch when I have "Extended user" like Profile class which is connected as OneToOne with User model

Answer (score 75):

You can use [`CurrentUserDefault`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault):

```py
user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    read_only=True, 
    default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
)
```

Comment: This isn't working anymore. Viz https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#380

Comment: It works for me when using PrimaryKeyRelatedField as above. From the docs I think it's only if you are using HiddenField that you shouldn't set read_only=True?

Comment: Works for me with HiddenField in Django 3.0

Comment: Had to drop read_only and pass queryset argument  for me to work. django 3.1

Answer (score 47):

It depends on your use case. If you want it to be "write-only", meaning DRF automatically populates the field on write and doesn't return the `User` on read, the most straight-forward implementation [according to the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#advanced-field-defaults) would be with a `HiddenField`:

```
class PhotoListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(
        default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(),
    )
```

If you want want it to be readable, you could use a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` while being careful that your serializer pre-populates the field on write - otherwise a user could set the `user` field pointing to some other random `User`.

```
class PhotoListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        # set it to read_only as we're handling the writing part ourselves
        read_only=True,
    )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Finally, note that if you're using the more verbose `APIView` instead of `generics.ListCreateAPIView`, you have to overwrite `create` instead of `perform_create` like so:

```
class PhotoListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
    )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # add the current User to the validated_data dict and call
        # the super method which basically only creates a model
        # instance with that data
        validated_data['user'] = self.request.user
        return super(PhotoListAPIView, self).create(validated_data)
```

Comment: I was able to use validated_data['created_by_id'] = self.context['request'].user in my serializer

Comment: This is the most well rounded answer for sure.  Thanks olieidel

Comment: Is there a reason that for the readable version we have to override `perform_create` whereas we can use `default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()` with the HiddenField?

Answer (score 20):

You can avoid passing the `user` in your request and you won't see it in the output but DRF will populate it automatically:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.HiddenField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = (
            'user',
            'other',
            'fields',
        )
```

Comment: what if I want to see it in the output?

Comment: @mtf then you can use: `user = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=User.objects.all(), default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())`

Answer (score 15):

As of [DRF version 3.8.0](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#380) ([Pull Request discussion](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/5886)), you can override `save()` in serializer.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
...

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['id', 'user', 'photo']

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        """Include default for read_only `user` field"""
        kwargs["user"] = self.fields["user"].get_default()
        return super().save(**kwargs)
```

Comment: This was particularly helpful to my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

@DaveBensonPhillips's answer might work in your particular case for some time, but it is not very generic since it breaks OOP inheritance chain.

`ListCreateAPIView` inherits from `CreateModelMixin` which [saves](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3.5.3/rest_framework/mixins.py#L26) the serializer already. You should always strive to get the full chain of overridden methods executed unless you have a very good reason not to. This way your code stays DRY and robust against changes:

```
class PhotoListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    ...
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.validated_data['user'] = self.request.user
        return super(PhotoListAPIView, self).perform_create(serializer)
```

Answer (score 4):

You will have to override the default behavior of how `generics.ListCreateAPIView` creates an object.

```
class PhotoListAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(hidden=False)
    authentication_classes = (SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.request.method == 'POST':
            return CreatePostSerializer
        else:
            return ListPostSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Copy parsed content from HTTP request
        data = request.data.copy()

        # Add id of currently logged user
        data['user'] = request.user.id

        # Default behavior but pass our modified data instead
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

The `.get_serializer_class()` is not necessary as you can specify which fields are read-only from your serializer, but based on the projects I have worked on, I usually end up with 'asymmetric' serializers, i.e. different serializers depending on the intended operation.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this:

```
def post(self, request, format=None)

        serializer = ProjectSerializer(data=request.data)
        request.data['user'] = request.user.id


        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me in serializers.py, where I am also using nested data. I want to display created_by_username without having to lookup other users.

```
class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    A list may be created with items
    """
    items = ItemSerializer(many=True)

    # automatically set created_by_id as the current user's id
    created_by_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True,
    )

    created_by_username = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True
    )


    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'description', 'is_public',
            'slug', 'created_by_id', 'created_by_username', 'created_at',
            'modified_by', 'modified_at', 'items')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        items_data = validated_data.pop('items', None)
        validated_data['created_by_id'] = self.context['request'].user
        validated_data['created_by_username'] = self.context['request'].user.username
        newlist = List.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for item_data in items_data:
            Item.objects.create(list=newlist, **item_data)
        return newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension to DRF's serializer below

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class AuditorBaseSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    created_by = serializers.StringRelatedField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(), read_only=True)
    updated_by = serializers.StringRelatedField(default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault(), read_only=True)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        # if creating record.
        if self.instance is None:
            kwargs["created_by"] = self.fields["created_by"].get_default()

        kwargs["updated_by"] = self.fields["updated_by"].get_default()
        return super().save(**kwargs)
```

and it can be used as follows

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer, AuditorBaseSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SelfEmployedBusiness
        fields = (
            'created_by',
            'updated_by',
        )
```