# Django Rest API : Add current User to User Field with Token Auth

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

**Requirements :**

```
Python 3.7
Django 2.0
```

I'm working on my `Django Rest API` and I would like to add current user into my User field when an object is created but it doesn't work up to know.

I'm using `JWT Authentification` with my API Rest.

I followed this question : [How to set current user to user field in Django Rest Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518273/how-to-set-current-user-to-user-field-in-django-rest-framework)

But it doesn't seem to work with my code.

I have my **serializers.py** file :

```
class IndividuCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer) :

    class Meta :
        model = Individu
        fields = [
            'Etat',
            'Civilite',
            'Nom',
            'Prenom',
            'Sexe',
            'Statut',
            'DateNaissance',
            'VilleNaissance',
            'PaysNaissance',
            'Nationalite1',
            'Nationalite2',
            'Profession',
            'Adresse',
            'Ville',
            'Zip',
            'Pays',
            'Mail',
            'Telephone',
            'Utilisateur',
            'Image',
            'CarteIdentite',
            ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
       obj = Individu.objects.create(**validated_data)
       Identity_Individu_Resume(self.context.get('request'), obj.id)
       return obj
```

And my **/Api/views.py** file :

```
class IndividuCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView) :

   permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
   authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
   queryset = Individu.objects.all()
   serializer_class = IndividuCreateSerializer

   def user_create(self,serializer):
      serializer.validated_data['Utilisateur'] = self.request.user
      return super(IndividuCreateAPIView, self).user_create(serializer)
```

In order to try my API, I configured a pythonic file which makes the same job than an other web application.

This file looks like :

```
import requests

mytoken = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IkFkbWluIiwiZXhwIjoxNTE5Mzc4MDExLCJlbWFpbCI6InZhbGVudGluQGRhdGFzeXN0ZW1zLmZyIiwib3JpZ19pYXQiOjE1MTkzNzQ0MTF9.7AKpbNEcdir2FLU064QzwwZGiylV-P7LBm1nOJIekwE"
url = 'http://localhost:8000/Api/Identification/create/'

filename1 = '/Users/valentin/Desktop/Django/DatasystemsCORE/Media/pictures/photo.jpg'
filename2 = '/Users/valentin/Desktop/Django/DatasystemsCORE/Media/Carte_Identite/carte_ID.gif'
files = {'Image' : open(filename1,'rb'), 'CarteIdentite': open(filename2,'rb')}

data = {
    "Etat": "Vivant",
    "Civilite": "Monsieur",
    "Nom": "creation",
    "Prenom": "via-api",
    "Sexe": "Masculin",
    "Statut": "Célibataire",
    "DateNaissance": "1991-11-23",
    "VilleNaissance": "STRASBOURG",
    "PaysNaissance": "FR",
    "Nationalite1": "FRANCAISE",
    "Nationalite2": "",
    "Profession": "JJJ",
    "Adresse": "12, rue des fleurs",
    "Ville": "STRASBOURG",
    "Zip": 67000,
    "Pays": "FR",
    "Mail": "",
    "Telephone": ""
    }

response = requests.post(url, files=files, data=data, headers={'Authorization': 'JWT {}'.format(mytoken)})

print(response.text)
```

My object is well-created but my User field is empty.
How I could write this in order to add Current User into the User Field ?

Thank you !

Comment: You can pass additional arguments to serializer's save method. Check example here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save

Comment: I tried to write this : `def save(self) :
  return {'Utilisateur' : self.request.user}` but it doesn't seems to work. I'm searching yet

Comment: You need to pass it as `save` argument in view's `create` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass current user directly to serializer's save method inside view:

```
class IndividuCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView) :

   permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
   authentication_classes = (JSONWebTokenAuthentication,)
   queryset = Individu.objects.all()
   serializer_class = IndividuCreateSerializer

   def perform_create(self,serializer):
      serializer.save(Utilisateur=self.request.user)
```

Comment: I tried but User field still don't fill. Is it possible that this issue according to my authentificate method ?

Comment: @Deadpool is `Utilisateur` is field you trying to fill? Or ou have other model's field `user`? In this case you need to add this field to serializer and pass user as save's kwarg `serializer.save(user=self.request.user)`

Comment: @Deadpool does your users authenticated? If you add `print(self.request.user` to `perform_create` do you see User instance of AnonymousUser?

Comment: My user is authenticated by JWT. So I assume he is well-authenticated with the associated token in my python file.

Comment: @Deadpool that's weird. Can you add full code of `IndividuCreateAPIView`? `user_create` method looks custom. Did you try to replace it with `perfrom_create`?

Comment: I made a mistake and write `perform_create` to the wrong place !
Your script seems to work very well ! Thank you very much ! I will put my project as an open source project and I'm searching Django developper in order to improve this soft with me ;)