# Get logged user information in serializers Django Rest + Django JWT

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt

I need to get a FK info in logged User on ModelSerializer to add a new models.

In this case User->Business and Client->Business. 
When post client I need to set Business id using the logged user Business.

It's important to say all other models have the same behavior. I'm looking for some generic solution for this problem.

Client Model

```
class Client(SoftDeletionModel):
    object = ClientManager
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, related_name='business_clients', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=511, verbose_name=_('Company Name'))
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=14, verbose_name=_('CNPJ'))
```

User Model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
"""User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, related_name='business', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

ClientSerializer

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    business = serializers.IntegerField() # here how can I get user.business?
    deleted_at = serializers.HiddenField(default=None)
    active = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False, allow_blank=True)
    password_contract = Base64PDFFileField()

class Meta:
    model = Client
    fields = '__all__'
    validators = [
        UniqueTogetherValidator2(
            queryset=Client.objects.all(),
            fields=('cnpj', 'business'),
            message=_("CNPJ already exists"),
            key_field_name='cnpj'
        ),
        UniqueTogetherValidator2(
            queryset=Client.objects.all(),
            fields=('email', 'business'),
            message=_("Email already exists"),
            key_field_name='email'
        )
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

### Access request inside a serializer

Within the serializer you have access to the serializer context that can include the request instance

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Client.objects.create(
            business=self.context['request'].user.business,
            **validated_data
        )
```

Request is only acessible if you pass it when instantiate the serializer

### Pass extra arguments to a serializer via `save()`

It is also possible to pass extra arguments to a serializer during the `save()` method call

```
def create(self, request, **kwargs)
    serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save(business=request.user.business)
    ...
```

### Create a mixin to set business

Finally, a more reusable way is create a mixin for views that provides `create` and/or `update` actions, then overwrite `perform_create()` and `perform_update()` methods

```
class BusinessMixin:
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(business=self.request.user.business)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(business=self.request.user.business)


class ClientViewSet(BusinessMixin, ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ClientSerializer
    queryset = Client.objects.all()
    ...
```

`ModelViewSet` (basically`CreateModelMixin` and `UpdateModelMixin`) use these methods to call the `save()` method from serializer when executing its actions (`create()`, `update()` and `partial_update()`, i.e. `POST`, `PUT` and `PATCH`)

Comment: Nice Lucas! I saw the first and second solution but really didn't like it. But your third solution is very nice and clever. In spite of that, my solution is bad for any reason ? Or yours better for some situations ? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Set a `default` value for a serializer field does not prevent it from being supplied by a client request (check this [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#default)). My answer was based on this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35518273/7727181)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by serializers.CurrentUserDefault() magic I wrote CurrenUserBusinessDefault but set_context with current user business.

```
class CurrentUserBusinessDefault(object):
    def set_context(self, serializer_field):
        self.business =  serializer_field.context['request'].user.business

    def __call__(self):
        return self.business

    def __repr__(self):
        return unicode_to_repr('%s()' % self.__class__.__name__)
```

So it's accessible like the default method

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    business = BusinessSerializer(default=CurrentUserBusinessDefault())
```