# Add new field and value to the request - Django - Django Rest Framework (viewset, serializer)

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, django-rest-framework

i have a endpoint in django-rest-framework and receive a object **name** and **date**.

I need include **user** (fk_model_user) in object before save my database, how save or update including new item in body request?

- **Viewset:**

```py
    class MusicStylesViewSet(
        mixins.ListModelMixin,
        mixins.CreateModelMixin,
        mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
        mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
        mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
        viewsets.GenericViewSet
    ):
        permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
        queryset = MusicStyleModel.objects.all()
        serializer_class = StyleSerializer
```

- **Serializer:**

```py
    class StyleSerializer(ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = MusicStyleModel
            fields = ('id', 'name', 'date', 'user')
```

- **Model:**

```py
    class MusicStyleModel(models.Model):
        id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, null=False)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False, blank=False)
        date = models.DateTimeField(null=False, blank=False)
        user = models.ForeignKey(
            CustomUser,
            null=True,
            blank=False,
            on_delete=models.CASCADE
        )
```

**Example - Post Request:**

```py
    {
        "name": "test",
        "date": "2021-05-14T15:47:06.794639-03:00"
    }
```

**Example - Post Response:**

```py
    {
        "id": "810ae929-2f6d-411a-8d10-77c8f613a8ac",
        "name": "test",
        "date": "2021-05-14T15:47:06.794639-03:00",
        "user": "c6fbbfee-2f16-49f3-b4cd-b99e05a66ea8"
    }
```

> "id": "810ae929-2f6d-411a-8d10-77c8f613a8ac", **automatically generated in the model**

> "user": "c6fbbfee-2f16-49f3-b4cd-b99e05a66ea8" **user id request intercepted, and save**

Comment: maybe this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35518273/how-to-set-current-user-to-user-field-in-django-rest-framework

Comment: you can overwrite create method in your serialzier or post method in  your viewset (APIView). based upon what exactly you want user to be.

Comment: @ItsMilann What is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: i dont see much difference, except serializers dont have access to request object directly so I would suggest to create it in apiview

Comment: @ItsMilann To create ApiView, do I need to modify my current apiview?

Can you demonstrate how I would do this in the 'apiview' and 'serializer'?

Comment: so do you want user field to be null or any other specific user?

Comment: @ItsMilann In the request the field is null, but "viewset" or "serializer" set user_id value in user field when to save or update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve using create:

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.response import Response

class MusicStylesViewSet(
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    queryset = MusicStyleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StyleSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        data = serializer.validated_data
        data['user'] = request.user

        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you're going to use all these mixins better use ModelViewSet'

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

class MusicStylesViewSet(
    mixins.ListModelMixin,
    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
    viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
    queryset = MusicStyleModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StyleSerializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = StyleSerializer(request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.validated_data['user'] = request.user
            serializer.save()
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: make sure the user is logged in. Can you check the value of request.user, what  does it show?

Comment: i placed request.user print, but not print.

Comment: I have updated the statement, please try that.