# Django: NOT NULL constraint failed: appname_post.user_id

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following django rest framework serializer and view for a model `Post`, and the models defined for the app are as following.

Now I wanted to test the API, so tried to "create" a new post from the API page, but then I got an error `IntegrityError at /api/posts/`  `NOT NULL constraint failed: appname_post.user_id`.

So then I tried to debug and checked its `request.data` value, it says it only has `title` and `content` but not `user_id`, as I could expect from the error above.

But now I have no idea how to tell the API automatically relate the `user_id` field to `request.user.id`. [Isn't not enough](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280007/retrieving-a-foreign-key-value-with-django-rest-framework-serializers) to just add the `user_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.id')` line? I could do "retrieve", "update", "patch" etc but just cannot "post" (create).

Thanks for your help.

- serializer and view

```py
class DevPerm(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return True 

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return True

class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    user_id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.id')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('url',
                  'id',
                  'title',
                  'content',
                  'created_at',
                  'voters',
                  'comments',
                  'user_id',
                  )
                  
        read_only_fields = (
            'id', 
            'created_at', 
            "voters", 
            "comments", 
            # "user_id",
            )

class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, DevPerm,]
```

- models

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='posts', default="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    title = models.TextField(blank=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='votes', default="")

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments', default="")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments', default="")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/35520084/4151233 will tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override `perform_create` method inside you ModelViewSet.

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, DevPerm,]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working like a charm. But one thing what's the difference by adding the `return super().perform_create(serializer)` line? I tried the SO answer @Marco commented above, and only `serializer.save(user=self.request.user)` without the `return` also works.